# Copy NuxtJS generated static files to parent folder

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, config

I'm using NuxtJS to generate **static files** on my server through SSH. How to copy all generated files from the `/dist` folder to  `../../` (parent <- parent) after running `npm run generate`?

I tried setting the dist `dir:` to `../../` but *nuxt.config.js* doesn't allow parent folders for this.

> options.generate.dir cannot be a parent of or same as rootDir

```
  generate: {
    dir: '../../',
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `target: 'static'` in your nuxt.config.js and it should work.

**nuxt.config.js:**

```
target: 'static',
generate: {
   dir: '../../my-site'
},
```